# Android Studio 3.0.1 - Cannot Create Class

Tags: java, class, android-studio

I've seen similar questions regarding my issue but non of them answer or solved my issue. I'm getting the following two responses when trying to create a new Java Class in Android Studio 3.0.1.

1. Unable to parse template "Class"
   Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface
   package com.floresfandit.myapplication;
2. Error parsing file template: Encountered ").\n */\n" at File Header.java[line 2, column 40]
   Was expecting one of:
   "[" ...
   "}" ...

I have no code written, other than what was populated when selecting the Blank Activity. I've already re-installed Android Studio 3.0.1 three times. If by chance I don't get an exact answer is it possible to create blank activities, which will create both the Java Class and XML file and just use the Java Class as a workaround?

Comment: I figured out a fix that worked, but is not the best solution I'm sure. I created a second Windows profile on my Windows 7 Laptop for Programming only. When it prepared Android Studio for use on the New Profile it asked if I wanted to import settings from the other User Profile and I said not too. It works now, I can create JAVA class Files on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the 1st Error when I create new class
To resolve that
You have to Create a new activity that includes Java class and layout at the same time !!